# How to write co-ordinates in German numbering format in a text file using CATIA vb script?

Tags: vbscript, catia

I am working with CATIA vb script and I am getting the co-ordinates of the points from the model and writing it in a text file. While writing it in a text file I want to write in German numbering format, where "." is read as ",".

Thank you!!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/goglobal/bb688127.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/238kz954%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) to change "." to ",":

```
>> d = 1234.56
>> s = CStr(d)
>> g = Replace(s, ".", ",")
>> WScript.Echo d, s, g
>>
1234,56 1234.56 1234,56
```

[FormatNumber()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ws343esk%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) allows a more fancy startegy/result:

```
>> d = 1234.56
>> s = FormatNumber(d, 3, True, False, True)
>> g = Replace(Replace(Replace(s, ".", "*"), ",", "."), "*", ",")
>> WScript.Echo d, s, g
>>
1234,56 1,234.560 1.234,560
```